# Circular Queue using Dynamic Array

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, queues

I'm learning data structures from "Fundamentals of Data structures in C" by Sahni . In the topic, Circular Queue using Dynamic Array, the author has mentioned below point,

> Let *capacity* be the initial capacity of the circular  queue,We must first
>   increase the size of the array using realloc,this will copy maximum of *capacity* elements on to the new array. To get a proper circular queue configuration, we must slide elements in the right segment(i.e, elements A and B) to the right end of the array(refer diagram 3.7.d). The array doubling and the slide to the right together copy at most **2 * *capacity* -2** elements.

I understand array doubling copies at most *capacity* elements. But how does array doubling and slide to right copy at most **2 * *capacity* -2** elements??[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the author is just saying the circular list has capacity of $n-1$ where $n$ is the total cells. When the array is doubled there is copying of these $n-1$ elements to new array in addition with shifting of these $n-1$ elements in the worst case, thus making it total $2n-2$ doubling and sliding in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

In above example queue capacity is 8. A circular queue can have capacity - 1 elements. Here it is 7.
While array doubling those 7 elements are copied. Then suppose front = 0 and rear = 7, then the elements from 1 to 7 has to be moved to the right. Here it copies 7 elements. Hence the total is 7 + 7 = 14.
2 * 8 - 2 = 14

Comment: (`A [data structure instance] can have capacity - 1 elements` sounds a fun definition of *capacity*.) "The -1" is an artefact of an implementation just keeping two indices besides "the array". More *element copies* than there are *valid elements* is sub-standard (in the eyes of this not-so-humble coder).